# Azure Worker will not connect to Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

So I have two separate projects for a cloud project I am deploying to Azure, I used to use the old grouping to ensure my roles had access to local services.. now that the old portal has been retired that grouping style is gone... which is fine - except, I cannot for the life of me get my worker role to connect to the new virtual network.

I have deployed a web-role, and it connects just fine to the virtual network (which utilizes the same set of services), and I have configured the web and worker-role the same in the service configuration file. The only thing I can think is there is a different way I need to configure the worker, vs, the web role?

The config I have in my serviceconfiguration file:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <Dns>
        <DnsServers>
            <DnsServer name="MyDNSServer" IPAddress="11.11.11.11" />

        </DnsServers>
    </Dns>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="West-US" />
    <AddressAssignments>
        <InstanceAddress roleName="CPTWorkerRole">
            <Subnets>
                <Subnet name="MySubnet" />
            </Subnets>
        </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Please let me know any ideas on the worker role... please do not suggest based upon web-role experience, as I am not having issues connecting the web role...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is any difference and so, just to make sure, I made a quick attempt just now - I've create a cloud project with 2 instances of a web role and an instance of a worker role and successfully deployed both roles onto an existing VNET I had using the same configuration -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
  <Role name="WebApplication9">
    <Instances count="2" />
  </Role>
  <Role name="WorkerRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="yossinet" />
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="WebApplication9">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="Subnet-1" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="WorkerRole1">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="Subnet-1" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```